How can I see Chrome Network activity i R? [httr, selenium?]
I'm wondering how I can in R visit a website and see the Network activity and responses as I would in Google Chrome and copy their associated attributes as url?
Dont even know where to start but I tried httr2
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football"

library(httr2)
response <- url %>% 
  httr2::request() %>% 
  httr2::req_perform()

should I be able to see all the information below in the response object somewhere?


httr2 only makes a single request (unless it get's redirected) and will not load any linked resources. Though you could use chromote. If you just need a list of loaded resources, you could perhaps use Performance API in chromote session:
library(chromote)
b <- ChromoteSession$new()

# request pattern from https://rstudio.github.io/chromote/#loading-a-page-reliably
p <- b$Page$loadEventFired(wait_ = FALSE)
b$Page$navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football", wait_ = FALSE)
#> <Promise [pending]>
b$wait_for(p)
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 157552.4

# evaluate js in chromote session, get result value
perf_entries <- b$Runtime$evaluate(
  'window.performance.getEntries()
  .filter(entry => entry.entryType == "resource" || entry.entryType == "navigation")
  .map(entry => ({e: entry.entryType, i: entry.initiatorType, u: entry.name}))', 
  returnByValue = TRUE)$result$value

# list of named lists, bind_rows() will handle this
dplyr::bind_rows(perf_entries)
#> # A tibble: 74 × 3
#>    e          i          u                                                      
#>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                                                  
#>  1 navigation navigation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football     
#>  2 resource   link       https://en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?lang=en&modules=ex…
#>  3 resource   script     https://en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?lang=en&modules=st…
#>  4 resource   img        https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/icons/wikipedia…
#>  5 resource   link       https://en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?lang=en&modules=si…
#>  6 resource   img        https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyrigh…
#>  7 resource   img        https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyrigh…
#>  8 resource   img        https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/1b/S…
#>  9 resource   img        https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4…
#> 10 resource   img        https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4…
#> # ℹ 64 more rows

Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0
